# Finding an item's index in an array

Tags: javascript, function

I was writing a function that takes two arguments, an array and a number, and returns the index of the number if it's present in the array. The issue I encounter is the fact that my code returns properly without the "else" part, however, when I add the code about returning "-1" it doesn't work properly and it seems as if the compiler only takes "return -1" into account, no matter what arguments I use. Could anyone help me solve this issue?

```
function search(arr, item) {
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(item===arr[i]){
        return i;
    }else if(item!==arr[i]){
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

It's always giving me an output of "-1", when it's supposed to give the index of the "item" argument if it's presents in the first array argument.

Comment: Well you exit when the first item does not match.... You do not allow it to check all the indexes

Comment: if your list is `[1,2,3]` and you search for 2 the else will catch at index 0 and return -1

Answer (score 4):

You need return -1 outside the loop so it only returns -1 if it makes it all the way through the loop without finding something. If it finds something before that, it will return the index:

```js
function search(arr, item) {
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(item===arr[i]){
            return i;
        }
     }
     return -1;
}
console.log(search([1, 2, 3], 5))
console.log(search([1, 2, 3], 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about this sequentially.

Let's say your array is `[1, 2, 3]` and you're looking for 3.

The function loops over the array. The first value considered is 1. That actives the `else` block and returns -1 before the other values are even considered. Remember return means end of function execution.

In any case, you can greatly simplify the function:

```
return arr.indexOf(item);
```